# How test event logic?

Tags: android, kotlin, events, mvvm, mocking

In my ViewModel i have next fun:

```
fun onTitleClick(titleName: Int) {
    when (titleName) {
        R.string.about_terms_service -> {
            termsOfServiceItemClickEvent.postValue(
                ViewModelEvent(
                    WebViewFragment.newBundle(
                        url = TERMS_LINK,
                        title = "Terms of Service"
                    )
                )
            )
        }
        R.string.about_open_source_licenses -> licenseItemClickEvent.postValue(ViewModelEvent(R.string.about_open_source_licenses))
    }
}
```

And have next Event class:

```
open class ViewModelEvent<out T>(private val content: T? = null) {

    var hasBeenHandled = false
        private set

    /**
     * Returns the content and prevents its use again.
     */
    fun getContentIfNotHandled(): T? {
        return if (hasBeenHandled) {
            null
        } else {
            hasBeenHandled = true
            content
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns the content, even if it's already been handled.
     */
    fun peekContent(): T? = content
}
```

In Event class i have next `fun getContentIfNotHandled()` with some logic. How i can test this logic my Robolectric tests?

Also here is some code from my fragment:

```
viewModel.licenseItemClickEvent.observe(this, Observer<ViewModelEvent<Int>> {
    it?.getContentIfNotHandled()?.let { activity?.addFragment(LicensesFragment()) }
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with next solution:

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner::class)
class ViewModelEventTest {

    @Test
    @Throws(Exception::class)
    fun getContentIfNotHandledTest() {
        val viewModelEvent = ViewModelEvent(5)

        assertFalse(viewModelEvent.hasBeenHandled)
        assertEquals(5, viewModelEvent.getContentIfNotHandled())
        assertTrue(viewModelEvent.hasBeenHandled)
        assertNull(viewModelEvent.getContentIfNotHandled())
    }
}
```